# Can I add Windows to my systemd-boot bootloader if I have separate EFI partitions?

Tags: multi-boot, uefi, bootloader, systemd

I've just installed Arch Linux on to a new set of partitions on my Windows 8 machine.  In doing so, I created a new 512MB EFI partition for Linux to load from, leaving the existing Windows EFI partition untouched.  (I'm not sure if this was the right thing to do.)

Now systemd-boot isn't recognizing my Windows installation.  It's not a huge problem, since I can still get into the Linux bootloader from within Windows, but I'd like to be able to stick to one bootloader if possible.

How can I get systemd-boot to recognize my Windows bootloader?  Is it matter of copying files across from one partition to the other?  Or do I need to combine them in some way?

Comment: x-posted to Unix/Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219731/can-i-add-windows-to-my-systemd-boot-bootloader-if-i-have-separate-efi-partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to both. Systemd-boot cannot read any partitions outside its own. However, you *should not have* more than one EFI partition per disk (its file layout was explicitly designed to be shared between different operating systems).

Comment: I agree that systemd-boot can't read another ESP; however, I disagree with the assertion that a computer should have just one ESP. The EFI specification explicitly permits multiple ESPs, and there are situations in which having more than one is desirable or even necessary. That said, in the case of Donkey_2009, folding them together is probably in order. Alternatively, switching from systemd-boot to rEFIt, rEFInd, GRUB Legacy, or GRUB 2 is another option.